# Serial Number of Bootable device

Tags: windows, hard-drive, wmic

I have to get the serialnumber of the disk on which my operating system is installed.

I know in order to get serial number i need to run:

```
>wmic diskdrive get serialnumber,capabilities
Capabilities  SerialNumber
{3, 4}        AI92NXXXXXXXX2G02
{3, 4, 7}     1172XXXXXX030
```

There are no attributes to check if the OS is installed on this disk.

Comment: _check if the OS is installed_ on a particular disk drive? I doubt that it's possible using `wmi`. However, you can check where the running instance of Windows was booted from (`wmic OS get BootDevice,SystemDevice,SystemDirectory`) and further info from `wmic path Win32_BootConfiguration get /value`…

Comment: Bascially i want to find the serial number of the disk on which the OS is installed

Comment: I tired to `wmic partition where Bootable=True` and then tried to backtrack to disk didn't help

Comment: I don't see why this question is closed. It is very on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using `wmic partition where Bootable=True` and then backtrack to `Win32_DiskDrive` (a possible approach):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
  wmic path Win32_DiskPartition where "Bootable=True" get DeviceID /Value
') do ( 
  for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%g in ("%%G") do (
    set "_DiskPartition=%%h"
    REM ECHO set "_DiskPartition=%%h"
    call :GetDiskDriveIdAndOutput
  )
)
echo Possibly no linkage to a logical disk:
2>NUL wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk ^
  ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Antecedent ^
        /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition ^
        /RESULTCLASS:Win32_DiskPartition  
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:GetDiskDriveIdAndOutput
for /F tokens^=^2^ delims^=^" %%B in ('          
    wmic path Win32_DiskPartition where "Bootable=True" ASSOC /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
  ') do (
      if NOT "%%B"=="%_DiskPartition%" (
        REM ECHO set "_DiskDriveId=%%B"
        set "_DiskDriveId=%%B"
      )
)
echo Bootable: Drive = "%_DiskDriveId:\\=\%", Partition = "%_DiskPartition%"
wmic path Win32_DiskDrive get Capabilities,DeviceId,SerialNumber
REM wmic path Win32_DiskDrive Where "DeviceId='%_DiskDriveId%'" get Capabilities,DeviceId,SerialNumber
goto :eof
```

Of course, it's improvable from **actual output**

```
Bootable: Drive = "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0", Partition = "Disk #0, Partition #0"
Capabilities  DeviceID            SerialNumber
{3, 4}        \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  NXXXXXXXXK4R2DT
{3, 4, 7}     \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  S0NFJNXXXXXXXX
```

to something like

```
Capabilities  DeviceID            SerialNumber      Bootable
{3, 4}        \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  NXXXXXXXXK4R2DT   True
{3, 4, 7}     \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  S0NFJNXXXXXXXX
```