# Get the drive letter from Partition Index

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I want to get the drive letter from Partition Index.

```
wmic path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition WHERE Antecedent='Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=\'Disk #1 AND Partition #0\'' Get Dependent
```

Result: No Instance(s) Available

Comment: Remove the `where` clause and run again; do you get any instances then?

Comment: `2>NUL wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Antecedent /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition  /RESULTCLASS:Win32_DiskPartition` could be a [good start point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674353/3439404)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should output your information, you'd obviously need to parse it further to select the drive letter from that.

```bat
WMIC Partition Where (DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0") Assoc /ResultRole:Dependent 2>NUL
```

Alternatively:

```bat
WMIC Partition Where (DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0") Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_DiskPartition WHERE (DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1") Assoc:list /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition /ResultRole:Dependent ^| Find "Caption="') DO (
    ECHO %%a
)
Pause
```

It is show empty.

I need result as: Caption=C: